# uWSGI, Nginx, Flask app service keeps failing

Tags: nginx, service, deployment, flask, uwsgi

Going to my app produces a 502 gateway error. Found out that it was because my how_lit.service is failing. But I am having trouble finding out why.

Tried editing the application and the ini document. Cannot figure out whats wrong.

*The Nginx and uWSGI services are up and running fine.*

**Service Status:**

```
    lit@digitalocean:~/howlit$ sudo service how_lit status
[sudo] password for lit: 
● how_lit.service - uWSGI instance to serve how lit rest api
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/how_lit.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-08-04 00:30:44 EDT; 5 days ago
  Process: 14294 ExecStart=/home/lit/howlit/env/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/lit/howlit/howlit.ini (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14294 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 04 00:30:44 digitalocean systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to serve how lit rest api.
Aug 04 00:30:44 digitalocean uwsgi[14294]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/lit/howlit/howlit.ini
Aug 04 00:30:44 digitalocean systemd[1]: how_lit.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 04 00:30:44 digitalocean systemd[1]: how_lit.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 04 00:30:44 digitalocean systemd[1]: how_lit.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Directory and Permissions:**

```
lit@digitalocean:~/howlit$ ls -l .
total 16
drwx---r-x 6 lit www-data 4096 Jul 29 11:47 env
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data  202 Aug  3 23:29 howlit.ini
-rwx---r-x 1 lit www-data 1203 Aug  3 23:01 how_lit_restapi.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lit www-data   72 Aug  3 23:27 wsgi.py
```

**/etc/systemd/system/how_lit.service:**

```
lit@digitalocean:~/howlit$ cat /etc/systemd/system/how_lit.service 
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve how lit rest api
After=network.target


[Service]
User=lit
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/lit/howlit/
Environment="PATH=/home/lit/howlit/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/lit/howlit/env/bin/uwsgi --ini    /home/lit/howlit/howlit.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**howlit.ini file:**

```
lit@digitalocean:~/howlit$ cat howlit.ini 
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

uid = lit
gid = www-data



master = true
processes = 5


socket = how_lit_restapi.sock

chmod-sock = 666

vacum = true

die-on-term = true


gto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

**Tried running it by hand:**

```
lit@digitalocean:~/howlit$ /home/lit/howlit/env/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/lit/howlit/howlit.ini 
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/lit/howlit/howlit.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.13.1 (64bit) on [Tue Aug  9 18:28:25 2016] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 29 July 2016 11:48:08
os: Linux-4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016
nodename: digitalocean
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/lit/howlit
detected binary path: /home/lit/howlit/env/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 1896
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230]
```

permission error again?

SOLVED IT: By sending my socket into tmp, but still getting bad gateway error when I navigate to my site :(

Comment: Check if SELinux is allowing you to create and connect to sockets.

Comment: well I see that I have a sock file created, so does that not mean  I cannot ? lol

Comment: nevermind just solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem.

First I checked my services.

```
sudo service nginx status
sudo service uwsgi status
sudo service how_lit status
```

then I saw them all running and up but was still getting the bad gateway error. Well after checking the logs had no errors. I had to assume my configs. 
Then I realized my mistake....I never restarted all of it, just certain parts at certain times. So I restarted every single one as such:

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service uwsgi restart
sudo service how_lit restart
```

now it works.

About the permission issue I tried it by putting the socket into the /tmp directory that way www-data group users can access it as well as root. I learned that you need to be able to create the socket and allow access to the system for it.

I moved it out of tmp btw later for production as I was told that was not best practice.